# How to step inside an overloaded operator while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, operator-overloading

Take for example the following code:

```
    public static void Main()
    {          
        Console.WriteLine(Integer.zero - new Integer(5));             
    }
```

I'm trying to debug what happened when the `-` (minus operation) is called but when I try to debug by pressing F11 (step into) it just goes inside the constructor and toString()...

How can I debug inside the overloaded `-` operator?

Comment: To closers: This looks like a good question. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The debugger steps over properties and operators in managed code by default. In most cases, this provides a better debugging experience.

To enable stepping into properties or operators, choose **Debug > Options and Settings**. On the **Debugging > General page**, clear the **Step over properties and operators (Managed only)** checkbox.